# How to remove any query except `callback` for specific URLs with RewriteRule?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

The current `RewriteRule` removes any query except query `callback` for any URL.

```
# Remove question mark and parameters
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?#\ ]*)\?[^\ ]*\ HTTP/ [NC]
# Query rewrite exceptions
##RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !^/api.*?callback=.* #does not work
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !callback=
RewriteRule .*$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

How to avoid query `callback` rewrite just from URL `^api\/?([^\/]*)$`? Excepted result:

- no rewrite for /api?callback=1, /api/user?callback=1, /api/user/2?callback=1
- rewrite for /apis?callback=1, /user?callback=1, /api/user?foo=1 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable `RewriteRule` for **index.php**, need to add in query rewrite exceptions.

This rules works fine and fixes this issue:

```
# Remove question mark and parameters
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
# Query rewrite exceptions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*
RewriteRule .*$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally understood your question...

Replace these lines:

```
##RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !^/api.*?callback=.* #does not work
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !callback=
```

with this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !^/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*
```

**Important notice:**

if your script isn't located in the document root, but, i.e., in dir `/htest`,
and full URL looks like mine: `http://localhost/htest/api/?callback=1`, then you have to put full path to API in your RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !^/htest/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*
```

You can overcome that by beginning your regex with `!/api` instead of `^/path/to/api`, but `/foo/api` and `/bar/api` will be skipped from rewriting too.

**Update:**

this .htaccess works fine in document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?#\ ]*)\?[^\ ]*\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !^/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*
RewriteRule .*$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=temporary,L]
```

you may try using it without any other rules to check what is wrong

**Update 2**

If you have other condition, i.e.,

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

repeat RewriteCond before it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} !^/api(/.*)?\?callback=.*
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

also to be able to use these rules in `/foo` subdir, replace `^/api` with `^/foo/api`

Comment: You may receive redirect to /index.php because of some other rule.
Also clear your browser cache and try to use `R=temporary` instead of `R=301` while debugging since permanent redirects are cached and you may see results of your previous rewrite attempts

Comment: Thanks, your `RewriteRule` actually works like you have explained. But it break when after used `RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`. Any solution? Also are there any way to use `^/api` option even when .htaccess is not in root (file location `/foo/.htaccess`, URL rewrite `/foo/api`, `RewriteCond` for `^/api` and not full path, since the project `/foo` could be located in any path)?

Comment: The example I provided was for .htaccess located in document root, index.php should be there too.

If you put your script into **/foo**, add `RewriteBase /foo` and change `!^/api` into `!^/foo/api` too

Comment: Your **Update 2** returns `Error 404`. Any issue?